# Why does the square root of n! grow exponentially faster than exponential functions?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I am going through [Normal Subgroup Reconstruction and Quantum Computation Using Group Representations](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~amnon/Papers/HRT.stoc00.pdf) by Hallgren et al.

In the proof of the theorem $6$ of the paper on page 632, the authors go on proving the difference between the probabilities of sampling all irreps, $|p - q|_1$ of a subgroup inside the symmetric group $S_n$.

$$
\begin{align}
|p - q|_1 &=  \Sigma_{\rho} \mid p_{\rho} - q_{\rho} \mid \\
          &\le \Sigma_{\rho} \frac{d_{\rho}}{n!} 2^{O(n)} \sqrt{n}^{n / 2} \\
          &\le \Sigma_{\rho} \frac{\sqrt{n!}}{n!} 2^{O(n)} \sqrt{n}^{n / 2} \\
          &\le \frac{2^{O(n)} \sqrt{n}^{n/2}}{\sqrt{n!}} \\
          &= 2^{O(n)} \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{n}^n}} {\sqrt{n!}} \\
          &\le 2^{O(n)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left( n / 2 \right)!}} \lll 2^{-\Omega(n)}
\end{align}
$$

How is $2^{O(n)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left( n / 2 \right)!}} \lll 2^{-\Omega(n)}$?

Comment: I strongly object to the haphazard mix of $=$, $\leq$ and $\lll$, whatever the latter is supposed to mean here. There are two components to this: 1) Agreeing on how to read these notation-abusive terms. 2) [Showing that one term dominates the other](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth).

Comment: @Raphael, I didn't mixed those symbols. It was from the proof by the authors I was referring to.

Comment: This seems to be a purely mathematical question, with no computer science content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Throwing away gutter, this is the claim:

$\qquad\frac{c^n}{\sqrt{(n/2)!}} \to 0$ with at least exponential rate as $n \to \infty$.

That is, the sqare root of $(n/2)!$ grow (at least) exponentially faster than exponential functions.

You can prove this by showing that

$\qquad\frac{c^n}{\sqrt{(n/2)!}} \sim 2^{-g(n)}$ for some $ g \in \Omega(n)$.

Use Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 9):

$\log(n!)=\Theta(n\log n)$, (see [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)), hence

$\frac{2^{O(n)}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)!}}=2^{O(n)-\log\sqrt{\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)!}}=2^{O(n)-\Theta(n\log n)}=2^{-\left(\Theta(n\log n)-O(n)\right)}=2^{-\Omega(n)}$.

Comment: Wow.... that is something I think should (can?) not be done with Landau terms.

Comment: Maybe in this context the Landau notation may be unnecessary. Still, I'm gonna leave this here for now (unless OP has any problems).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any approximations. Compare $c^n$ and $(n!)^{1/2}$: As soon as $n > c^2$, $(n!)^{1/2}$ grows exponentially faster because going from n to n+1, one grows by a factor c, and the other by a factor greater than c.